# .ajax returns 500 error using mvc C#, can't get a success response. Just want a simple check that returns success or failure

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to program a "simple" .ajax call. When a button is pressed, I want to check to see if the email in one of the fields of my form is a valid email. If so, I want to progress to the method which attempts to send the email.

Here is my .ajax call in JavaScript:

```
var emailAddress = $("#EmailAddress_Field").val();

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: checkEmailUrl,
    data: emailAddress,
    contentType: "json",
    success: function () {
        self.sendEmail(); //currently just prints "success"
    },
    error: function () {
        self.showFailure();
    }
});
```

Here is my method in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult CheckEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
    }
    catch(System.FormatException e)
    {
        return Json(false);
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

I've changed everything around, originally my C# method was `async` and returned a `Task<ActionResult>` but I seemed to be having race issues so I thought it better to make it synchronous. I have also tried returning in the format `Json(new { Success = false })` but this did not seem to work either. I've tried adding the `traditional: true` flag under the .ajax call, as suggested in another Stack question, but to no avail. The `contentType` has also gone back and forth from `application\json` to `json`.

Currently, whether the email is valid or not, upon button press the `error` function is performed. Under Chrome's Inspect > Network tab I can see the call to `CheckEmail` but the status is 500, with the response `{"ClientMessage":"Unknown Error has occurred.", "Code":1}`, and the call stack's most recent call is in jquery.js send:

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send((options.hasContent && options.data) || null); // There is an error here
```

The second most recent call is in jquery.js ajax:

```
try {
    state = 1;
    transport.send(requestHeaders, done); // Call was here
} catch (e) {
...
```

Using Debug and stepping over I can tell that my C# function is returning `Json(true)` correctly when an email is valid, but somehow the Server is not parsing this correctly and it errors.

If anyone knows how to get .ajax to report a success, please let me know.

Comment: A 500 Error is a general error on the server. You will want to check your Server logs to determine what is generating the 500 Error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix ajax and remove content type json

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: checkEmailUrl,
    data: {emailAddress:emailAddress},
      success: function () {
        self.sendEmail(); //currently just prints "success"
    },
    error: function () {
        self.showFailure();
    }
});
```